# tomcat 7 startup error on rhel 5.5

Tags: linux, tomcat, redhat

i'm trying to set up tomcat 7.0.35 on red hat 5.5.

When i try to start tomcat i have this error in catalina.out

```
WARNING: error instantiating 'org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager' referenced by java.util.logging.manager, class not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager not found
   <<No stacktrace available>>
WARNING: error instantiating '1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler,' referenced by handlers, class not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler,
   <<No stacktrace available>>
Exception during runtime initialization
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   <<No stacktrace available>>
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   <<No stacktrace available>>
```

I'm using JDK 1.7.0_01 and i set up the JAVA_HOME and PATH

I've the same error with tomcat 6

Can someone help me??

Comment: what path is set for JAVA_HOME ?

Answer (score 4):

- Install complete, Compatible `JDK from Oracle (SUN) or IBM`
- Set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the root directory of
  the compatible JDK

> $`JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01`
>
> $ `export JAVA_HOME`

- Put the compatibale JDK's bin directory on the front of your `PATH`
  environment variable.

> `$    PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`
>
> `$    export PATH`

- Find the java executable of the incompatible JDK, usually
  `/usr/bin/java` and move it out of the way, like this:

> $`cd /usr/java`
>
> $`mv java java.moved`

- Then, check to make sure your java executable points to the JDK you
  have installed:

> `$ which java`
>
> `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01/bin/java`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I got it resolved by specifying proper JRE_HOME. Basically I made JRE_HOME same as JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

include following property in catalina.sh

-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager